# Nix and GCC - `cannot find crt1.o`

Tags: gcc, nix

I'm running Nix on WSL with Ubuntu 18.x.

I installed GCC with `$ nix-env -i gcc` which installed `gcc-7.3.0`.

I'm trying to use GCC to compile a simple CPP file (generated by Ferret). But GCC is coming up with the following error:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -x c++ test_1.cpp -o test_1
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It seems that I expected Nix to include common dependencies along with GCC (`build-essential` equivalents), which I assume is not true.

Searching using Nix (`nix-env -qaP 'gcc'`, `nix-env -qaP --description | grep -i gcc`) doesn't provide much help.

Other posts mention installing `gcc-multilib` (apt package). The only mention of that in Nix are testing packages:

```
$ nix-env -qaP --description | grep -i multilib
nixpkgs.tests.cc-multilib-gcc                                            cc-multilib-test                               
nixpkgs.tests.cc-multilib-clang                                          cc-multilib-test
```

I'm at a loss as to how to get a build environment working. I cannot find any documentation as to what packages I need to get going. This is pretty simple stuff.

Comment: The path `/usr/bin/ld` is a clue that something is misconfigured; Nix doesn't use `/usr`. Have you considered creating a Nix expression so that you can use `nix build` to compile your program?

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa I haven't, no. I don't know much about nix's depths. Re: ld, Interesting point, but I haven't installed a nix version, surely I shouldn't have to? `$ which ld; /usr/bin/ld; $ which gcc; /home/<user>/.nix-profile/bin/gcc`.

Comment: Isn't it possible to do this with `nix-shell` and not needing to create a nix expression? i.e. `nix-shell -p gcc_multi` and then `gcc <file>` and `./a.out`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, things are done differently with Nix. Instead of installing tools and libraries like you'd do with most distros, when using Nix you create a "Nix expression" which declares your build dependencies and instructions for compiling your program. For example, say you have a `hello.cc` with this source code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    cout << "Hello, World!";
    return 0;
}
```

To compile it with Nix you can use a `default.nix` file (in the same directory) like this:

```
let
    pkgs = (import <nixpkgs>) {};
    gcc = pkgs.gcc;
    stdenv = pkgs.stdenv;
in
    stdenv.mkDerivation {
        name = "hello";
        version = "1.0.0";
        src = ./.;
        phases = [ "unpackPhase" "buildPhase" "installPhase" ];

        buildPhase = ''
            ${gcc}/bin/g++ -std=c++11 -x c++ hello.cc -o hello
        '';

        installPhase = ''
            mkdir -p $out/bin
            cp hello $out/bin
        '';
    }
```

...which you can build like this: `nix build`

You'll end up with a `./result` symbolic link which points to the `$out` directory used above. The `installPhase` above copies the binary to `$out/bin`, so the program can be executed by running `./result/bin/hello`

The Nix language is described in its [documentation](https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#nix-package-manager-guide) and you can get an overview of how to use it to build things from the Nixpkgs [documentation](https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/).

Comment: This doesn't seem right. I'm just using the nix package manager. I'm not after a full OS/Build system abstraction. I have enough to learn with the tools I have. I'm looking for something to reduce my workload, not add to it. Surely there is just some missing package that I need to install alongside GCC?

Comment: @Rebs, the thing to keep in mind is that Nix is no ordinary package manager. Thus some concepts from other package managers, such as the idea that if you install two packages they should be able to "see" each other, do not apply. For example, if you have code which requires libgtk and you try to compile it by first installing gcc and gtk, it will not work. gcc would not be able to "see" libgtk. Instead you'd need to create a Nix expression which provides gtk as a dependency. Nix will then create a "user environment" in which gtk is visible to gcc. Compilation would then proceed as normal.

Comment: Ok, that's totally different to what I expected. It sounds interesting, but a burden. I think I'm going to jump ship to something simpler. I appreciate the help.

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa is there really no way to make this work? I thought the purpose of `nix-env -i packagename` was to put such dependencies into `~/.nix-profile/bin`, `~/.nix-profile/lib`, etc. so that they can be seen and used. Even if I've fully bought into Nix's abstractions, I still need to be able to use these tools in a traditional manner, like to download and compile a C++ project that doesn't come with a `default.nix`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply getting a Nix shell with gcc works.

```bash
nix shell nixpkgs#gcc # with flakes
nix-shell -p gcc # without flakes
```

and then going `gcc <anything>` seems to work.

If you want other dependencies you can add them as well:

```bash
nix-shell -p pkgconfig gcc openssl
g++ $(pkg-config --libs --cflags openssl) solution.cpp
```

or eventually build up a .nix file which is the non ad-hoc version of this